# Can't import generated typings file create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, create-react-app, es6-modules

It's my first time creating a typescript react npm module, and I am trying to import one of the type definitions in my project that is using the new npm module. VSCode intellisense is able to find and suggest the one of the automatically generated `.d.ts` files, but the application fails to load it. What is going on?

```
./src/components/MyPage.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@myorg/component-library/build/Input/Input.types' in '/Users/jbaczuk/path/to/project/src/components'
```

If I change the import path to `'@myorg/component-library/build/Input/Input.types.d'` it throws:

```
./node_modules/@myorg/component-library/build/Input/Input.types.d.ts 2:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> export declare enum Type {
|     text = "text",
|     number = "number"
```

**Input.types.d.ts**

```
export declare enum Type {
    text = "text",
    number = "number"
}
export interface InputProps {
    type?: Type;
}
//# sourceMappingURL=Input.types.d.ts.map
```

**MyPage.ts**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Type } from '@myorg/component-library/build/Input/Input.types.d';

export default function MyPage(): JSX.Element {

{/** ... more stuff **/}}

return (
{/** ... more stuff **/}}
  <Input
    onChangeValue={onChangeText}
    type={Type.text}
  />
{/** ... more stuff **/}}
)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "My Project",
  "private": true,
  "repository": "git@github.com:MyOrg/MyProject.git",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@myorg/component-library": "../../component-library",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:tailwind": "tailwind build src/tailwind.css -o src/tailwind.output.css",
    "watch:tailwind": "chokidar 'src/**/*.css' 'src/**/*.scss' --ignore src/tailwind.output.css -c 'npm run build:tailwind'",
    "start": "npm-run-all build:tailwind --parallel watch:tailwind start:react",
    "start:react": "PORT=3002 react-scripts start",
    "prebuild": "run-s build:tailwind",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint '*/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix",
    "check-types": "tsc"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.9.5",
    "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "chokidar-cli": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": ">=10",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "build"
  ]
}
```

### Component Library

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@myorg/component-library",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/myOrg/ComponentLibrary.git"
  },
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "description": "MyOrg react component library",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "module": "build/index.esm.js",
  "files": [
    "build"
  ],
  "types": "build/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf build && rollup -c --environment NODE_ENV:production",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix --ext .ts",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "storybook:export": "build-storybook",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "create": "node ./util/create"
  },
  "author": "Jordan Baczuk",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^18.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.2.2",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.2.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.2.2",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "lint-staged": ">=10",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "rollup": "^2.44.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "3.1.8",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.30.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged && npm test"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ],
    "*.js": "eslint --cache --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/titillium-web": "^4.2.2",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.17"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.js**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.tests.tsx"
  ]
}
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import packageJson from './package.json'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  external: ['styled-components'],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    postcss({
      minimize: true,
      modules: true,
      use: {
        sass: null,
        stylus: null,
        less: { javascriptEnabled: true }
      },
      extract: true
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript()
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `package.json` & `tsconfing.json` ?

Comment: @Dilshan yes that would probably be helpful, added!

Comment: I mean the package.json of `@myorg/component-library`. I see you are not publishing your package to NPM. So where does the `../../component-library` pointed to ? Did you typed that path manually ?

Comment: @Dilshan sorry I added those files as well. It is a private npm package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working, and learned a few things.

1. Enums are not types.

> enum is not a type which means that it generates js code not like types and interfaces. https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/809#issuecomment-385187297

2. In order to export an enum from the npm module, you have to explicitly export it from the main module file:

**MyPackage/src/index.ts**

```
import Card from './Card/Card'
import Input from './Input/Input'
import Form from './Form/Form'
import Link from './Link/Link'
import Text from './Text/Text'
import Button from './Button/Button'
import { HeroIcons } from './style/heroicons'

export { Card, Input, Form, Link, Text, Button, HeroIcons }
export * from './Input/Input.types'
```

Now I am able to import it like:

```
import { Type } from '@myorg/component-library';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit surprised you're loading types from the types.d file direct and with a build path! I'd expect rather `import { Type } from '@myorg/component-library`.

That's because as part of creating the package.json for a typescript-authored npm library you'd be defining a main property pointing to the place that exports all the Javascript properties and a types property pointing to the place that exports the typescript types you want.

If that main entry point (because of your build process) is actually `build/index.js` and the corresponding types file is `build/index.d.ts` then you'd never directly reference the build folder or files when importing - pointing to the right path is dealt with by the bundling process.

Take a look at a mainstream (but simple) typescript npm module like https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated-next/blob/master/package.json ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/unstated-next )

You can see the main property pointing to the file which should export the javascript names https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated-next/blob/master/package.json#L6 and the types property pointing to the file which should export the types https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated-next/blob/master/package.json#L9 and these happen to be in the 'dist' folder but this is never referenced when importing it as per the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/unstated-next

Comment: thanks for the response! I did think that was weird, and it is curious that the build process does create a `build/index.d.ts` file as well as the `build/index.js`, but the `build/index.d.ts` file only contains type definitions that are defined in the `src/index.ts` file in my source code. There are others files like `build/util.d.ts` etc that are generated. Maybe it's because I'm using rollup? I added my files to my question.